# Random UV rotation

Tags: texturing, uv

When I unwrap the model, how to procedurally rotate UV faces so that the texture does not appear seamless ?

I now need to rotate every UV element separately. I would like to do it in one go. Is it possible to do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, switch your ***Pivot Point*** to ***Individual Origins*** and then <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate them around their centers.

[image]

Comment: This may be it but can I rotate  faces in random direction?  With this method every face is rotating in the same direction.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no simple, built-in way of doing that.  You can do random proportional editing but it really messes up the symmetry of the islands.  One thing you can do is enable Island selection mode, select half of the quads, rotate them, Ctrl+I to invert the selection, and rotate them the other way.  Not random, but gives you more disparity.

Comment: Also, in your 3D View, you can Checker Select faces when doing UV mapping.

Answer (score 2):

You may try **R** key along with the angle value

eg. R 90 or R 180

If you wish to rotate the individual box than you may combine above keys, with setting **Pivot Point** to **Individual Origins**